# My UINavigationitem's TitleView getting expanded in ios 6

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, titleview

In my app I have applied an image on uinavigation item. It is running fine in iOS 5 but getting expanded on iOS 6. I have no left or right bar button item in navigation bar. I searched too much but couldn't find answer.

Here is my code:

```
UIImageView *navigationImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 98, 34)];
navigationImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"topNav-logo.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView=navigationImage;
```

and image shows like this:

[image: screenshot]

It should be displayed like lower image but it is displayed like expanded in iOS 6 it works good in iOS 5.

The result is:

[image: result screenshot]

Comment: Give some code (how you add the image) and a screenshot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue starting at iOS 6, and found the craziest workaround:

Create one more UIImageView of the same dimension. Then add the navigationImage as a subview to that. In my case this will prevent the auto resizing.

```
UIImageView *workaroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 98, 34)];
[workaroundImageView addSubview:navigationImage];
self.navigationItem.titleView=workaroundImageView;
```

If anyone finds a proper solution or an explanation please post it.

Comment: Thanks Vanja It solved my problem but i want to know what was problem there

Comment: Try setting the contentMode of the original image:
`navigationImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;`

Comment: No, that neither centers the titleView nor fits it to the imageView frame.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in my project, and works fine under iOS 5 and iOS 6. Can you try this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topNav-logo.png"]];
```

Also, be sure to have both @2x and regular sizes of the image.

Comment: I used this solution but the result remains same as well as i always have @2x images because my minimum deployment target is iOS 5.0. The result if you want to see i show to you  at above.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Can you please verify that the regular and `@2x` images are named the same (maybe a typo?) and that the regular and `@2x` images are actually the correct dimensions (in my case I have a 120x20 for the regular image and 240x40 for the `@2x`)?

Comment: I always take images in double resolution as here image dimension is 195 × 68 pixels but the image view frame is 98 x 34 pixal