# Size of Image on UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

I want to put Custom image on my UINavigationBar,

When i tried this two code snippets,

```
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]]];
```

**And**

```
    UIButton *logoView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,70,30)];
    [logoView setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logoView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoView;
```

image which i can see on my Device is getting blur or it is getting streched.

I made image with Resolution of `180*40`(Width*Height)

I want to know the exact size of Image. what, it would be ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If image size is **140x35** then set `imageView`'s frame size same. Otherwise It will obviously get stretched.

Comment: You want to add a logo on navigationBar at center position ?

Comment: yes, On UINavigationBar

Comment: Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988642/my-uinavigationitems-titleview-getting-expanded-in-ios-6

Comment: I was having the same issue

Comment: I would like to use an `UIView` instead of `navigationBar` and will hide the navigation for this screen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use this

```
UIImageView *navigationImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 98, 34)];
navigationImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"topNav-logo.png"];

UIImageView *workaroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 98, 34)];
    [workaroundImageView addSubview:navigationImage];
    self.navigationItem.titleView=workaroundImageView;
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what is `navigationImage` ??

Comment: what should be the size of image ?

Comment: same as imageview or vice versa

Comment: Very nice solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Create Image with size **(320 x 44)** and set as a Title like bellow..

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourImageView;
```

See whole example like bellow...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
        UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imgView;
        [imgView release];
}
```

Comment: I want to put title image and not Background image on NavigationBar

Comment: @Krunal you try out this answer??

Answer (score 1):

You need to first initialize the titleView. and then set it the imageView as a subView:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];

self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.bounds];
[self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: it's working but still image is getting stretched, what should be the resolution of image ?

Comment: You can make the image which ever resolution you like,
you should check a couple of things though:
1. the image content mode should be aspectFit, so it wont get of ouf bounds when added to superView.
2. check image autoresizing as well (remove streching).
3. self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizesSubviews is default == YES, try setting it to NO.

Comment: How to make image content mode aspectFit ?

Comment: imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: I tried this but still facing the problem `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:imageView.bounds];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.navigationItem.titleView.autoresizesSubviews=NO; 
    [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:imageView];`

Comment: What is the size of the imageView? it should be the image.size